# Convert String to java.util.Date in the (yyyy-MM-dd) format with return type of Date

Tags: java, string, date, simpledateformat

I am trying to convert String to java.util.date this way,

My Input string is :"2013-09-18"

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateAndTime {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            Date convertedCurrentDate = sdf.parse("2013-09-18");
            String strDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(convertedCurrentDate);
            System.out.println(strDate);

     }
}
```

Here convertedCurrentDate is giving output as ""Wed Sep 18 00:00:00 IST 2013"".

Actually I want to get output this way, 2013-09-18 and not ""Wed Sep 18 00:00:00 IST 2013""

So, I tried this way,

```
String strDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(convertedCurrentDate);
            System.out.println(strDate);
```

This is giving me output as 2013-09-18.

But the issue is I am getting this '2013-09-18' as string.

What i want is 2013-09-18 with java.util.date datatype and not String

i.e,

```
need to cast strDate to java.util.date.
```

Can anyone help me in this issue?

Thanks

Comment: parse does that - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)

Comment: A java.util.Date has no format!! `Wed Sep 18 00:00:00 IST 2013` is only the internal representation

Comment: why not just write a date logging method that uses that format?

Comment: I'm a little confused - you get a string as input and want to have a Date. And your problem lies in returning that Date to your String?

Comment: Date is a java complex binary object type, which could only have string representation over his toString() methods which returned value is of course of type string, too. So your questions makes no sense ;) Sorry. When you have a date object it will keep a date and when you want to print it anywhere or to transport the value then you have to convert it into a string.

Comment: @Rhayene .. I want this java.util.date strDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(convertedCurrentDate);
            System.out.println(strDate);

Comment: @Rhayene .. I dont want this String strDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(convertedCurrentDate); System.out.println(strDate);

Comment: @Sandy Why? It makes no sense _at all_ to want that.

Comment: uhm - why would you want to convert a Date to a Date with format (since your convertedData is already a Date? If you have your string - why not just use the parse method as you already do? And where is the problem to format it to a string before printing?

Answer (score 1):

**Reason:**
When using println java explicitly calls toString method on that object. When calling toString on Date object it may be using its default date format which leads to above output.

**Solution:**
For just printing purpose do what your doing

```
String strDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(convertedCurrentDate);  
System.out.println(strDate);
```

Comment: what i want is Date strDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(convertedCurrentDate);

Comment: new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(convertedCurrentDate) returns Object of type StringBuffer not Date

Comment: Yes i wan date as return type how to dot that?

Comment: Create your own class which extends from Date and override toString method. Or use Java 8's LocalDate object

Answer (score 1):

When you invoke System.out.println on a Date object the String representation of that object is printed. This is done by calling method toString() of the corresponding Date object.
The String representation of the Date object is predefined by the implementer of that class so you will always get a format like "Wed Sep 18 00:00:00 IST 2013"

You should always invoke the following on the Date object in order to print it in the format you want:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(dateObject)
```

To make your life easier, create a static object of the Date formatter and call it everywhere in your code like:

```
public static SimpleDateFormat MY_DATE_FORMATTER=  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

And call it like:

```
System.out.println(MY_DATE_FORMATTER.format(dateObject));
```

Answer (score 0):

Java does not allow Date format to be just the Date part ,whenever you create a Date Object it should contain the time part too even when its not there it is written as 00:00 .So you cannot have a formatted Date Object but you can always get a formatted String.